# TextMate Doesn't Like Programmer Dvorak Layout

Tags: macos, textmate, dvorak

I've been eager to try out the Programmer Dvorak keyboard layout, so I downloaded it from http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/.

Strangely (to me at least), with it activated, I can't input anything into TextMate.  TextMate is perfectly happy with the Dvorak options that come as standard with Snow Leopard, but this just shuts it down.

It seems ironic that a keyboard layout designed to maximize programming efficiency should be violently incompatible with an editor designed to do the same!  How can I get TextMate to accept this new layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, curiously it seems to have started working now.  Possibly I just needed to restart the computer?

In anycase I suspect this was a non-question - sorry!